# Parser for HTML-like string returned via JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am using a web service to retrieve some results via their REST API and one of the properties in the JSON response contains HTML. However, it looks like some kind of markup language that can be converted to HTML. This is a sample of what it looks like:

> ". ul. li. Limit 1 voucher per purchaser; additional 2 vouchers may be sent as gifts. /li. li. Limit 1 voucher redemption per individual. br. /li. li. Appointments are required and subject to availability. Merchant cancellation/rescheduling policy of 24 hours applies; voucher subject to forfeiture. /li. li. span style. "color: initial;". Signed waiver required. br. /span. /li. li. span style. "color: initial;". Must be 18. with valid ID to redeem. br. /span. /li. li. Customer must be deemed eligible prior to treatment; if deemed ineligible, customer may use the paid value toward another service from merchant or contact Amazon Local to receive a refund. br. /li. li. Additional fee applies for touch-ups. /li. li. All services must be redeemed during a single visit by same customer. br. /li. li. Available for use immediately after purchase. /li. li. PROMOTIONAL VALUE EXPIRES 180 DAYS FROM THE PURCHASE DATE. /li. li. PAID VALUE DOES NOT EXPIRE. /li. /ul."

I have looked at several markup languages and Templating engines(Jade, Handlebars, dot.js, dom.js, etc.) but none seem to fit the pattern. I need to convert this back to HTML. To avoid reinventing the wheel by building parser using RegEx, I wanted to check:

1. Is this a standard approach to sending HTML in JSON string that I am completely unaware of (I have always just used HTML without issues)?
2. Is there a Javascript library, or a Templating engine to convert it back to proper HTML on the client?

Answer (score 0):

1. No, it's not a normal way. I think there might be a problem with the script that creates the json file.
2. I can only suggest try to use the `.replace()` in a way that will convert it back to html. Also try using regex.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried .replace() before, and it is sub-optimal solution, and the RegEx can get messy especially because the pattern seems to allow inline style tags also. Unless I know the format of the markup, it is going to be tricky.